# Instantiating a function parameter that is of private type

Tags: c++

Given a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
   struct PrivateType {};
public:
   static void func(PrivateType) {}
};
```

I can't do this because PrivateType is private:

```
MyClass::func(MyClass::PrivateType());
```

But I can do this:

```
MyClass::func({});
```

So I'm instantiating a private type, what looks like, outside of the class scope. Is that an implicit conversion from an initializer list? If so, when a parameter is implicitly converted, does the conversion take place in scope of the class i.e. as if it was part of the body of the function? Why is that and is that always the case?

Comment: Just to confirm, the `static` keyword makes the `func()` accessible without an instance of the `MyClass` class.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Your issue is one reason I don't do nested classes or structures.  IMHO, nested classes add complexity to the code and trying to reuse them is now more difficult.

Comment: No no. The static is not important here. Might as well remove it from the example.
I mean that I effectively create an instance of MyClass::PrivateType outside of the MyClass class, which shouldn't be possible, because it's private.
It's not something I do. I stumbled upon this in 3rd party code and am just curious how it works.

Comment: There is no such things as "private types". There are private names. But names and types are different beasts. You could, [for example](https://godbolt.org/z/53rsbehTj), define a private struct and a public type alias for that struct. Given that aliases don't create new types, will that private struct be a private or a public type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{}` is a syntax called *braced-init-list*. It doesn't have a type or value category and doesn't represent any object or value like an expression does. It therefore also doesn't really make sense to consider something like a conversion from a `{}` to exist.

There are specific rules separate from those for expressions as arguments on how overload resolution considers _braced-init-list_s as arguments.

There are also rules separate from those for initialization from parentheses when initializing from a *braced-init-list*. However, after overload resolution, the function parameter is always initialized simply as if the argument was the initializer for the parameter in a copy-initialization, meaning that the `PrivateType` parameter object, which I will name here `private_type`, will be initialized as if by

```
PrivateType private_type = {};
```

in a local variable definition. However, this initialization always happens in the context of the caller. All of this is true for expressions as function arguments as well.

The initialization with the type as defined in your example would resolve to aggregate initialization, because `PrivateType` is an aggregate class. Since there are no members or base classes to initialize, the initialization then doesn't do anything.

None of this considers whether `PrivateType` is accessible (`private`) from the context of the caller, because accessibility only applies when deciding whether a member can be *named* (where e.g. overload resolution to a member function, constructor or operator overload counts as *named*). You are never using the name `PrivateType` in the caller though. `private` does not prevent construction of a member class in any context.

Comment: So basically you're saying it's ok to instantiate a private type outside its scope as long as I find a way not to mention the type explicitly? That sounds a bit like a design flaw of the accessibility system.

Comment: @chrisaverage Yes, I added a sentence to clarify that. `private` does not prevent a member class from being used. It is only as good as naming the member class with an impossible to guess random name would be. It is not meant to prevent use outside the class in general. For example if you have some member type used as a result type of your class member functions that the user should consider to be some unspecified type, then you want it to be `private`, but not impossible to be constructible for the user, so that they can still retrieve it with `auto`.